# ssh via bluetooth between two WT12 bluetooth modules

Tags: c++, ssh, embedded, embedded-linux

I use two WT12 bluegiga bluetooth modules. I need to transfer files between them via bluetooth in ssh. Has anyone tried doing something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to establish an IP network between them with PAN and then use scp.

I think this [HOWTO](http://bluez.sourceforge.net/contrib/HOWTO-PAN) can be a good start point.